# Comparing dates inside group using same reference

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, compare

I have a data table for different patients ("Spell") and several temperature ("Temp") measures for each patient ("Episode"). I also have the date and time in which each temperature was taken.

```
Spell Episode         Date    Temp
 1       3       2-1-17 21:00   40
 1       2       2-1-17 20:00   36
 1       1       1-1-17 10:00   37
 2       3       2-1-17 15:00   36
 2       2       2-1-17 10:00   37
 2       1       1-1-17 8:00    36
 3       1       3-1-17 10:00   40
 4       3       4-1-17 15:00   36
 4       2       3-1-17 12:00   40
 4       1       3-1-17 10:00   39
 5       7       3-1-17 17:30   36
 5       6       2-1-17 17:00   36
 5       5       2-1-17 16:00   37
 5       1       1-1-17 9:00    36
 5       4       1-1-17 14:00   39
 5       3       1-1-17 13:00   40
 5       2       1-1-17 11:00   39
```

I am interested in keeping all the measurements done 24h prior to the last one, I have grouped the observations by the spell and reverse date, but I am unsure on how to do the in-group comparison using the same reference (in this case, the first row for each group). The result should be:

```
    Spell Episode         Date    Temp
 1       3       2-1-17 21:00   40
 1       2       2-1-17 20:00   36
 2       3       2-1-17 15:00   36
 2       2       2-1-17 10:00   37
 3       1       3-1-17 10:00   40
 4       3       4-1-17 15:00   36
 5       7       3-1-17 17:30   36
```

Would appreciate any ideas that point me to the right direction.

Edit: Date is in d-m-yy H:M format. Here's dput from data:

```
structure(list(Spell = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Episode = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), Date = c("2-1-17 21:00", 
"2-1-17 20:00", "1-1-17 10:00", "2-1-17 15:00", "2-1-17 10:00", 
"1-1-17 8:00", "3-1-17 10:00", "4-1-17 15:00", "3-1-17 12:00", 
"3-1-17 10:00", "3-1-17 17:30", "2-1-17 17:00", "2-1-17 16:00", 
"1-1-17 9:00", "1-1-17 14:00", "1-1-17 13:00", "1-1-17 11:00"
), Temp = c(40L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 40L, 36L, 40L, 39L, 
36L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 39L)), .Names = c("Spell", "Episode", 
"Date", "Temp"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>)
```

Comment: Reproducible example would be great for this one.

Comment: And what's the format of the date?

Comment: Thanks, date format is d-m-yy, and I edited to add the dput outcome

Comment: Your expected result shows an additional row (Spell 5, Episode 6) which is outside of the 24 hrs window. Is this intended?

Comment: @UweBlock, not at all - that's a mistake, editing it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date2 = as.numeric(strptime(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))) %>% 
  group_by(Spell) %>% 
  filter(Date2 >= (max(Date2) - 60*60*24)) %>%
  select(-Date2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution using only `data.table` :

```
# convert Date column to POSIXct
DT[,Date:=as.POSIXct(Date,format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M',tz='GMT')]
# filter the data.table
filteredDT <- DT[, .SD[as.numeric(difftime(max(Date),Date,units='hours')) <= 24], by = Spell]

> filteredDT
   Spell Episode                Date Temp
1:     1       3 2017-01-02 21:00:00   40
2:     1       2 2017-01-02 20:00:00   36
3:     2       3 2017-01-02 15:00:00   36
4:     2       2 2017-01-02 10:00:00   37
5:     3       1 2017-01-03 10:00:00   40
6:     4       3 2017-01-04 15:00:00   36
7:     5       7 2017-01-03 17:30:00   36
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mydata$Date <- as.POSIXct(mydata$Date, format = '%d-%m-%y %H:%M', tz='GMT')
mydata <- mydata[with(mydata, order(Spell, -as.numeric(Date))),]
index <- with(mydata, tapply(Date, Spell, function(x){x >= max(x) - as.difftime(1, unit="days")}))
mydata[unlist(index),]

    Spell Episode                Date Temp
1:      1       3 2017-01-02 21:00:00   40
2:      1       2 2017-01-02 20:00:00   36
4:      2       3 2017-01-02 15:00:00   36
5:      2       2 2017-01-02 10:00:00   37
7:      3       1 2017-01-03 10:00:00   40
8:      4       3 2017-01-04 15:00:00   36
11:     5       7 2017-01-03 17:30:00   36
```

Comment: Why don't you use the data provided by th OP? Instead, you are supplying your own data where the `Date` column is already converted to class `POSIXct`?

Comment: The data sample was added by OP in an edit after I answered the question. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses two functions from Hadley Wickham's `lubridate()` package. This package is very handy when dealing with dates and times so I wonder why it hasn't been used in any of the other answers.

Furthermore, `data.table` is used because the OP has provided sample data of `data.table` class.

```
library(data.table)   # if not already loaded
# coerce Date to POSIXct
DT[, Date := lubridate::dmy_hm(Date)][
  # for each, pick measurements within last 24 hours
  , .SD[Date > max(Date) - lubridate::dhours(24L)], by = Spell][
    # order, just for convenience
    order(Spell, -Date)]
```

> ```
>    Spell Episode                Date Temp
> 1:     1       3 2017-01-02 21:00:00   40
> 2:     1       2 2017-01-02 20:00:00   36
> 3:     2       3 2017-01-02 15:00:00   36
> 4:     2       2 2017-01-02 10:00:00   37
> 5:     3       1 2017-01-03 10:00:00   40
> 6:     4       3 2017-01-04 15:00:00   36
> 7:     5       7 2017-01-03 17:30:00   36
> ```

Please note that the expected result given by the OP shows an additional row (Spell 5, Episode 6) which is outside of the 24 hrs window.

#### Data

As provided by the OP

```
DT <- structure(list(Spell = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Episode = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), Date = c("2-1-17 21:00", 
"2-1-17 20:00", "1-1-17 10:00", "2-1-17 15:00", "2-1-17 10:00", 
"1-1-17 8:00", "3-1-17 10:00", "4-1-17 15:00", "3-1-17 12:00", 
"3-1-17 10:00", "3-1-17 17:30", "2-1-17 17:00", "2-1-17 16:00", 
"1-1-17 9:00", "1-1-17 14:00", "1-1-17 13:00", "1-1-17 11:00"
), Temp = c(40L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 40L, 36L, 40L, 39L, 
36L, 36L, 37L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 39L)), .Names = c("Spell", "Episode", 
"Date", "Temp"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```